# Kernel source version number does not match

Tags: kernel, version

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. When I type 'uname -r' in the terminal, I get:

```
3.0.0-15-generic
```

I want to download the kernel source for the particular kernel version I am running. When I look on kernel.org, and then look inside kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/ I can only find source tarballs by the name of linux-3.0.x.tar.gz. My 'uname -r' has an extra '0' in it.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Is my kernel not a mainline one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `apt-get --download-only source linux-image-3.0.0-15-generic`

Ubuntu kernels are base on mainline ones, but aren't numbered the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu kernels are modified from the mainline source, to include additional drivers and fixes.  The code can be obtained in one of two ways.  Either using `apt-get source linux-image-<VERSION>` (do remember to substitute in the version you require), or from the Ubuntu Kernel Team git repositories.

For more details see our wiki at the URL below:

```
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/SourceCode
```